# How to get a value from a column based on second occurrence of a condition after first occurrence of another condition in R?

Tags: r

## Data

Following is a sample data frame:

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(Vehicle.ID = c(21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 
21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 
45L, 45L, 45L, 45L, 45L, 45L, 45L, 45L, 45L, 45L, 45L, 45L, 45L, 
45L, 45L, 45L, 45L, 45L, 45L, 45L), gap.dist = c(36L, 37L, 38L, 
39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 
52L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 
34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L), safept = c("no", 
"no", "no", "no", "dx_safe+CC2", "no", "no", "no", "no", "dx_safe", 
"no", "no", "no", "no", "no", "dx_safe+CC2", "no", "no", "dx_safe", 
"no", "no", "no", "no", "no", "dx_safe+CC2", "no", "no", "no", 
"no", "dx_safe", "no", "no", "no", "no", "no", "no", "no", "no", 
"dx_safe", "no")), .Names = c("Vehicle.ID", "gap.dist", "safept"
), row.names = c(NA, -40L), class = "data.frame")
```

## Goal

I want to create 2 columns. The first column is `safetylower` which should contain the value of `gap.dist` by `Vehicle.ID` at the FIRST occurrence of `"dx_safe"` in `safept` column. The second column is `safetyupper` which should contain either:

- the value of `gap.dist` by `Vehicle.ID` at the FIRST occurrence of
  `"dx_safe+CC2"` AFTER the FIRST occurrence of `dx_safe` (the value
  found before). This applies IF there is any occurrence of
  `"dx_safe+CC2"` after the first occurrence of `"dx_safe"`.
- OR the last value of `gap.dist` for a given `Vehicle.ID`

So, the desired output is something like following:

## Desired Output

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(Vehicle.ID = c(21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 
21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 
45L, 45L, 45L, 45L, 45L, 45L, 45L, 45L, 45L, 45L, 45L, 45L, 45L, 
45L, 45L, 45L, 45L, 45L, 45L, 45L), gap.dist = c(36L, 37L, 38L, 
39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 
52L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 
34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L), safept = c("no", 
"no", "no", "no", "dx_safe+CC2", "no", "no", "no", "no", "dx_safe", 
"no", "no", "no", "no", "no", "dx_safe+CC2", "no", "no", "dx_safe", 
"no", "no", "no", "no", "no", "dx_safe+CC2", "no", "no", "no", 
"no", "dx_safe", "no", "no", "no", "no", "no", "no", "no", "no", 
"dx_safe", "no"), safetylower = c(45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 
45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 34, 34, 34, 
34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 
34), safetyupper = c(51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 
51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 
44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44)), .Names = c("Vehicle.ID", 
"gap.dist", "safept", "safetylower", "safetyupper"), row.names = c(NA, 
-40L), class = "data.frame")
```

## What I have tried

I could only create the first column `safetylower` by using `match`. The following shows the code I tried that didn't achieve the goal. Please help.

```
library(plyr)
df <- ddply(df, 'Vehicle.ID', transform,
            safetylower = gap.dist[match('dx_safe', safept)], 
safetyupper = gap.dist[match('dx_safe+CC2', safept)])
```

## EDIT

What if there are more than one sets of `dx_safe` and `dx_safe+CC2`? Consider the following data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(Vehicle.ID=rep(c(5,6),each= 50), 
                 gap.dist = rep(seq(from=10, to=59), 2),
                 safept = rep(c(rep('no', 5), 'dx_safe+CC2', rep('no', 4), 'dx_safe', rep('no', 3), 'dx_safe+CC2', rep('no', 5), 'dx_safe', rep('no', 28), 'dx_safe+CC2'), 2))
```

Building on the same code as provided in both answers (they both work flawlessly),  how can I consider only the longer set (the one with longest number of rows in between) and get the `gap.dist` values for `safetylower` and `safetyupper` (by `Vehilce.ID`s)? The output should be:

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(Vehicle.ID = c(5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 
5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 
5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 
6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 
6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 
6, 6, 6, 6, 6), gap.dist = c(10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 
17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 
30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 
43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 
56L, 57L, 58L, 59L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 
19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 
32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 
45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 56L, 57L, 
58L, 59L), safept = structure(c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("dx_safe", 
"dx_safe+CC2", "no"), class = "factor"), safetylower = c(30, 
30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 
30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 
30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 
30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 
30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 
30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 
30, 30, 30), safetyupper = c(59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 
59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 
59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 
59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 
59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 
59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 
59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 59)), .Names = c("Vehicle.ID", 
"gap.dist", "safept", "safetylower", "safetyupper"), row.names = c(NA, 
-100L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Every question should look like this :) Great job!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your idea of using `match` is right, but you need some more lines of code. I'll stick with `ddply` since that's what you are using already.

```
ddply(df, .(Vehicle.ID), function(d) {
    i <- match("dx_safe", d$safept) # first match of "dx_safe"
    j <- i + match("dx_safe+CC2", d$safept[(i+1):nrow(d)]) 
        # first match of "dx_safe+CC2" after first match of "dx_safe"
    if(is.na(j)) j <- nrow(d) # if no match, set equal to the last entry
    transform(d, safetylower = d$gap.dist[i],
        safetyupper = d$gap.dist[j])
})
```

Note that this could be problematic and need adjustment if there is a chance that "dx_safe" does not appear at all in `d$safept` for a certain `Vehicle.ID`, but from the wording of your question I take it that it always does.

Also, +1 for the well-structured question :)

*EDIT* 
If you have many "pairs" of "dx_safe" and "dx_safe+CC2" and want to compare all the "distances" between them and select the largest one:

```
ddply(df, .(Vehicle.ID), function(d) {
    i <- which(d$safept == "dx_safe") # matches of "dx_safe"
    if (!length(i)) # if no matches of "dx_safe"
        return(transform(d, safetylower = NA, safetyupper = NA))
    j <- which(d$safept == "dx_safe+CC2") # matches of "dx_safe+CC2"
    j <- j[j > i[1]] # discard occurences before first "dx_safe"
    if (!length(j)) { # if no occurences of "dx_safe+CC2"
        lower.index <- i[1] 
        upper.index <- nrow(d)
    } else {
        intervals <- findInterval(j, i)
        distances <- sapply(j, function(x) x - max(i[i < x]))
        max.dist <- max(distances[!duplicated(intervals)])
        index <- match(max.dist, distances)
        lower.index <- i[index]
        upper.index <- j[index]
    }             
    return(transform(d, safetylower = d$gap.dist[lower.index],
        safetyupper = d$gap.dist[upper.index]))
})
```

The reason for testing for non-duplicated intervals in the above is we don't want to allow for the distance occuring between one "dx_safe" and one "dx_safe+CC2" to be selected as the maximum one, if there is another "dx_safe+CC2" between them. Is that right? i.e. if you have a vector `c("dx_safe", "no", "no", "dx_safe+CC2", "no", "dx_safe+CC2")` the distance is calculated as 3 and not 5. Let me know if this is not what you had in mind. Please test carefully before using because I don't have the data and can't verify it works as expected for all the edge-cases, but I think it should cover them.

Comment: Thanks. I do have many `Vehicle.ID`s which do not have `dx_safe` as well as `dx_safe+CC2` in `safept` column. Using the code as is results in `NA`s for those `Vehicle.ID`s and that's not a problem.

Comment: I found another problem: For some `Vehicle.ID`s there are many sets of  `dx_safe` & `dx_safe+CC2`. I want to get those values where there is longest number of rows in between. For example for a `Vehicle.ID`==10, the first occurrence of `dx_safe` is at 23rd row and first occurrence of `dx_safe+CC2` after it is at 33rd row (9 rows in between) . Then the 2nd set has 55 rows in between. I want to take the values from the second set. Is it possible? Should I ask a new question for this?

Comment: I don't think you need to ask a new question, you can add the new questions to the original post. Regarding your first comment, ie when "dx_safe" is missing, what should `safetylower` be set to in this case? The first value of `d$gap.dist`? And `safetyupper` to the last value of `d$gap.dist` even if "dx_safe+CC2" appears in `d$safept`?

Comment: If `dx_safe` is missing the corresponding `dx_safe+CC2` and  `Vehicle.ID` have no importance. Therefore, if the output contains `NA` due to this, there is no issue.

Answer (score 1):

How about a divide and conquer approach with `split()`

```
unsplit(lapply(split(df, df$Vehicle.ID), function(x) {
    lower <- which(x$safept=="dx_safe")[1]
    upper <- Filter(function(x) x>lower, which(x$safept=="dx_safe+CC2"))[1]
    if(is.na(upper)) {
            upper = nrow(x)
    }
    cbind(x, safetylower=x$gap.dist[lower], safetyupper=x$gap.dist[upper])
}), df$Vehicle.ID)
```

Here we basically create a data.frame for each "Vehicle.ID" then I used your definitions to find the appropriate row index for each value of "gap.dist". Finally, I add those values back to the data.frame and then `unsplit()` the data to restore the order.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You solution is slightly more efficient than @konvas's.